# React input fields not showing when Add button clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a task tracker app in React. I have an Add button that should toggle the visibility of the task input fields on and off, but it's not working.  If I set the default 'useState' of the button's property to 'true', the 'add task' fields will appear.  If not, they won't. They should toggle on and off with the click of the 'Add' button.

[image: Task Tracker with no fields]

When I set `const[showAddTask, setShowAddTask] = useState(true)` in '**App.js**' the fields will appear:

[image: Task Tracker with fields]

The 'Add' button should toggle the appearance of the 'Task', 'Day & Time' and the 'Reminder' checkbox but it doesn't work when the Add button is clicked.

Here are the components:

**App.js**

```
import Header from './components/Header'
import Tasks from './components/Tasks'
import AddTask from './components/AddTask'


const App = () => {
    // 'Add Task' fields initially not visible.
    const [showAddTask, setShowAddTask] = useState(true)
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTasks = async () => {
            const tasksFromServer = await fetchTasks()
            setTasks(tasksFromServer)
        }

        getTasks()
    }, [])

    //fetch tasks
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks')
        const data = await res.json()

        return data
    }


    // Add Task
    const addTask = (task) => {
        const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1
        const newTask = {id, ...task}
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask])

    }

    // Delete Task
    const deleteTask = async (id) => {
        await fetch(`  `)
        setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id))
    }

    //Toggle Reminder
    const toggleReminder = (id) => {
        setTasks(tasks.map((task) =>
                task.id === id ? {...task, reminder: !task.reminder} : task
            )
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header onAdd={() => setShowAddTask(!showAddTask)}
                    showAdd={showAddTask}
            />
            {showAddTask && <AddTask onAdd={addTask}/>}
            {tasks.length > 0 ? (
                <Tasks tasks={tasks}
                       onDelete={deleteTask} onToggle={toggleReminder}/>
            ) : (
                'No Tasks to Show'
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**AddTask.js**

```
const AddTask = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [day, setDay] = useState('')
    const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false)
    return (
        <form className={'add-form'}>
            <div className={'form-control'}>
                <label>Task</label>
                <input type = 'text'
                       placeholder={'Add Task'}
                       value={text}
                       onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className={'form-control'}>
                <label>Day & Time</label>
                <input type = 'text'
                       placeholder={'Add Day & Time'}
                       value={day}
                       onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className={'form-control form-control-check'}>
                <label>Set Reminder</label>
                <input type = 'checkbox'
                       value={reminder}
                       onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}
                />
            </div>

            <input type={'submit'} value={'Save Task'}
            className={'btn btn-block'}/>

        </form>
    )
};

export default AddTask
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const onClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e)

}

const Button = ({color, text}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}
                style={{backgroundColor: color}}
                className={'btn'}>{text}
        </button>
    )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
    color: 'steelblue'
}

Button.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
}
export default Button;
```

**Header.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Button from "./Button";

const Header = ({title, onAdd, showAdd}) => {
    return (
        <header className={'header'}>
            <h1> {title}</h1>
            <Button
                color={showAdd ? 'red' : 'green'}
                // make the text dynamic based on whether it's clicked or not.
                text={showAdd ? 'Close': 'Add' }
                onClick={onAdd}
            />
        </header>
    )
}

Header.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Task Tracker'
}

//'PropTypes is like a built-in type system for your properties
Header.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.string
}

export default Header;
```

**Task.js**

```
import {FaTimes} from "react-icons/fa";

const Task = ({task, onDelete, onToggle}) => {
    return (
        <div
             className={`task ${task.reminder && 'reminder'}`}
             onDoubleClick={() => onToggle(task.id)}>
            <h3>
                {task.text}<FaTimes style={{color:'red', cursor:'pointer'}}
                onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}/>
            </h3>
            <p>{task.day}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

**Tasks.js**

```
import Task from './Task'
const Tasks = ({tasks, onDelete, onToggle}) => {
    return (
        <>
            {tasks.map((task, index) => (
                <Task key={index} task={task}
                onDelete={onDelete}
                onToggle={onToggle}/>
            ))}
        </>
    )
};

export default Tasks
```

Here is the **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "react_crash_course",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test":  "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server":"json-server --watch db.json --port 5000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  }
}
```

I'm sure it's something real simple that I'm missing but I can't find it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have 2 errors. The first one which fixes your bug, is that you didn't add the onClick as prop in the button component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Button = ({color, text, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}
                style={{backgroundColor: color}}
                className={'btn'}>{text}
        </button>
    )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
    color: 'steelblue'
}

Button.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
}
export default Button;
```

The second one is unrelated and don't know if it's causing problems. You are fetching an empty string in your deleteTask method, so basically remove that line

```
    // Delete Task
    const deleteTask = (id) => {
        setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id))
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I found it in the Button component as well right after I posted.  Thanks!

Comment: The 'deleteTask' method is deleting the task in the UI properly. I'm working on the CRUD methods for manipulating the backend json data now.  Thanks for taking time out @Ignacio.